# express api responds to GET and POST but not PUT and DELETE through cors but responds properly when the request is local

Tags: express, cors, axios

When I'm sending a request to my express API through Axios, the GET and POST request respond correctly, but PUT and DELETE does not.
This is not a code problem as all my tests are passing, I believe this is related to CORS

I have installed `morgan` npm package to log the requests to the server.

The GET and POST are working fine, but PUT/DELETE are not and console.log() messages in those route handlers don't even show up!!!

The response from PUT and DELETE is 404

app.js

```
app.use(cors())
```

router.js

```
router.delete('/', (req, res) => {
// this log statement does not show up!
console.log('request recieved')
Controller.DeleteItem(req.body.data.title).then(() => {
res.redirect('/')
}
}
```

```
console output
OPTIONS 204 
DELETE 404
```

```
request
axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/', {
  data: {
    title: title
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was discussed outside SO : the issue was that the put and delete routes were placed inside the post route, the indentation (not appearing here) was obvious when seeing the whole code in context.